# como puedo solucionar error excepcion de java

Tags: javafx

quiero insertar datos de nombres y apellidos en una base de datos en sql server, el driver y todo lo demas esta bien instalado, pero al momento de insertar los datos desde el formulario creado en java me genera este error, he buscado en algunos blogs y no he dado, alguna ayuda que me puedan brindar para corregir este error  y poder insertar los datos, seria de mucha ayuda. gracias

**ConexionSQL.java**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class ConexionSQL {
    @FXML  private TextField nm;
    @FXML private TextField ap;
    @FXML private Button btn;



       @FXML
     private void btn(ActionEvent event) {

         Connection conn=null;
         try {

             conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=prueba", "sa", "milkas87");
             Statement insertar=conn.createStatement();
             insertar.executeUpdate("insert into cliente (nombre, apellido) values ('"+nm.getText()+"', '"+ap.getText()+"')");
             if(conn!=null)
                 System.out.println("conexion exitosa");

         } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

     }

        }
```

El **main**

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
         stage.setTitle("THANOS V1.0 ");
         Parent root = null;
         try {
         root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("VistaMain.fxml"));
         } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         }
         Scene scene = new Scene(root,  Color.WHITE);
         stage.setScene(scene);
         stage.show();
         }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);


    }
}
```

codigo xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="634.0" prefWidth="626.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.ConexionSQL">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="12.0" layoutY="17.0" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <children>
            <TextField id="nm" layoutX="238.0" layoutY="244.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="205.0" text="nombres" />
            <TextField id="ap" layoutX="238.0" layoutY="314.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="205.0" text="apellidos" />
            <Label layoutX="72.0" layoutY="245.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="137.0" text="NOMBRES" />
            <Button id="btn" layoutX="243.0" layoutY="418.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btn" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="195.0" text="AGREGAR" />
            <Label layoutX="66.0" layoutY="322.0" text="APELLIDOS" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

este es el error

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
>           at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
>           at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
>           at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
>           at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
>           at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
>           at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
>           at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>           at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
>           at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
>           at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
>           ... 48 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at application.ConexionSQL.btn(ConexionSQL.java:30)
>           ... 58 more

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el archivo ConexionSQL.java?, el log indica un error en la línea 30 de ese archivo, por lo que sería de ayuda identificarlo.

Comment: listo Francisco Bórquez.

Comment: Parece que la conexión no la está haciendo bien. Pasa la línea if(conn!=null) System.out.println("conexion exitosa"); justo después de intentar abrir la conexión y no debería mostrar el mensaje

Comment: @Rafael Lograste resolver el problema

Comment: @RaulCacacho nada, no se si me falta un event handler o algo para el boton, estuve leyendo y creo q me falta eso. no se que me dices , puede ser eso?

Comment: @Rafael el error da en esta lConexionSQL.java:30 y dice que va nula ya verificaste en debug que si haga la conexión?

Comment: alli coloco el debug en una imagen, me salen esos errores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se produce porque tienes mal enlazados los `TextField` declarados en el archivo FXML con los atributos correspondientes en el controlador.

Para realizar este proceso debe utilizar el atributo `fx:id` y no `id`, como has hecho. Al no estar bien enlazados los atributos `nm` y `ap` son nulos y por consiguiente si intentas hacer alguna llamada a un método de estos se lanzará una `NullPointerException`. Con el botón te  ocurre lo mismo, pero como no utilizas el atributo `btn` en el controlador no vas a tener problema. De todos modos te recomiendo que lo corrijas igualmente.

VistaMain.fxml corregido

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="634.0" prefWidth="626.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.ConexionSQL">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="12.0" layoutY="17.0" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="nm" layoutX="238.0" layoutY="244.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="205.0" text="nombres" />
            <TextField fx:id="ap" layoutX="238.0" layoutY="314.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="205.0" text="apellidos" />
            <Label layoutX="72.0" layoutY="245.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="137.0" text="NOMBRES" />
            <Button fx:id="btn" layoutX="243.0" layoutY="418.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btn" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="195.0" text="AGREGAR" />
            <Label layoutX="66.0" layoutY="322.0" text="APELLIDOS" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: gracias por todo!!!